# I can't import package in python

Tags: python, pip

I have problem, I download connector but I don't know how to install correctly, I understand that should I use pip install command?

I got this error:
[image]

Comment: Did you try to use `pip install` command?

Answer (score 1):

Use pip to install instead.

```
pip install cdata
```